# custom url - add attachment's id or name after post

Tags: url-rewriting, attachments, urls

I want to link to attachments but through its parent page.

/directors/piranha-bar/ shows all of that post's attachments on single.php

and i want /directors/piranha-bar/video/name-or-ID/ to still use single.php but have the variable $video captured.

How can i firstly make the links on the attachments into this format?
Then get wordpress to recognise this url, get the variable and go to single.php?

hope that's clear! best, Dc

Comment: There's definitely a way to do this but first can you tell us what happens if you go to the video url currently? Does it find the piranha bar page?

Comment: hello sancho, its says Not found. Loading template file 404.php.

Comment: Ok, will do a few tests and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

## Showing links to attachments in the desired format

Loop through the attachments and generate the link you want:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . 'video/' . $attachment->ID . '">' . apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title) . '</a>';
    }
}
```

## Getting the video variable and using single.php

Sorry it took me a while, there's a very simple way to do this in WordPress using url endpoints.

Paste the following code inside your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'video_endpoint' );
function video_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'video', EP_PAGES | EP_PERMALINK );
}
```

Make sure you refresh your permalinks by going to the admin permalinks page and hitting 'save changes'.

Once you've done that you can access the video parameter in your templates using:

```
echo get_query_var( 'video' );
```

**NOTE:**
Above where you see `EP_PAGES` this is the scope of where the endpoint will work. Some possible values are `EP_ALL`, `EP_ROOT`, `EP_PERMALINK`, `EP_CATEGORIES`, `EP_TAGS` and so on.

Comment: thanks sancho - tried all that but still get not found. Not sure how this will affect the solution but turns out we'll need to add a showreel variable too  making it, showreel/ID/video/ID/, thanks for your help so far...

Comment: Did you definitely flush the rewrite rules? I tested it myself and it works. You may need tweak the endpoint mask a bit though - I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Can you explain how the content is being managed here, eg. how are you splitting things up into showreels and videos in the back end?

Comment: yeh flushed them a lot! Directors and showreels are custom post_types. I basically want the extra variable(s) to define what loads/plays first on the directors page. That uses single-directors.php. The site isn't in the root of the domain either - http://sandbox.modernactivity.co.uk/independent_02/ but not sure if that makes a difference as .htaccess is in /independent_02/

Comment: mmm - array(EP_PAGES) instead EP_PAGES has made a difference but only works for one variable. Adding one for showreel too gives becomes 222/video/111...

Comment: Endpoints only work at the very end of a URL so you can't use that approach for showreels too. I'm a bit confused though - you want a url like "/directors/director/showreel/ID/video/ID" ?

Comment: hello - sorry for delayed response. I reckon /directors/director/showreel/ID/video/ID/ is what we are after now and i think it'd be handy to learn how to add as many variables as needed. Trying some options today so will let you know how i get on. Dc

Comment: @danielCrabbe Hi Daniel can you update your question with additional questions raised in the comments here? With rewrite endpoints you can add as much as you like to the URL but you have to do some processing on the query_var to get your key/value pairs out.

Answer (score 0):

in the end i used something like this -

```
function wpse13483_init() {

    add_rewrite_rule( 'directors/([^/]*)/showreels/([^/]*)/video/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=directors&name=$matches[1]&showreel=$matches[2]&video=$matches[3]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'directors/([^/]*)/showreels/([^/]*)/', 'index.php?post_type=directors&name=$matches[1]&showreel=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'directors/([^/]*)/photography/?', 'index.php?post_type=directors&name=$matches[1]&photography=1', 'top' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse13483_init' );


function wpa52794_query_vars( $vars) {
    $vars[] = 'video';
    $vars[] = 'showreel';
    $vars[] = 'photography';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa52794_query_vars' );
```

then to get the var on the page -

```
$show_photograpy = get_query_var( 'photography');
$selected_playlist = get_query_var( 'showreel');
```

Which works well. Only annoying thing is the url structure and links are ignored by xml sitemap plugins so the links with the variables only exist when i create the structure manually..

ie

```
$url="/directors/".$video_directors['director_names'][0].'/showreels/'.$video_directors['showreel_sections'][0].'/video/'.$vid_id.'/';
```